# Nuxt Generate with multiple dynamic route categories

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using `Nuxt.js` and am using my `nuxt.config.js` file to generate my dynamic page routes as static pages.

I am using a static `products.json` file locally rather than an API located in my static folder. I can now generate a list of dynamic routes statically

**nuxt.config.js file**

```
import servers from './static/servers.json'

const dedicatedServers = () => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            resolve(servers.dedicatedServers.map(server => `/products/dedicated-servers/${server.id}`))
        })
    }

 generate: {
    routes: dedicatedServers
}
```

How can I now add more product categories to my generate object?

I've tried to add an array but it does not work on the routes:

```
generate:{routes:[dedicatedServers,cloud-servers]}//does not work
```

I Have now tried to make a new method and return this but this does not work either.

**nuxt.config.js - Does not work**

```
import servers from './static/servers.json'

const dynamicRoutes = async() => {
    let dedicatedServers = () => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            resolve(servers.dedicatedServers.map(server => `/products/dedicated-servers/${server.id}`))
        })
    }
    const cloudServers = () => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            resolve(servers.cloudServers.map(server => `/products/cloud-servers/${server.id}`))
        })
    }
    const routes = dedicatedServers;
    return routes;
}


    generate: {
        routes: dynamicRoutes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create multiple categories by returning the promise from the generate object in which I mapped over each category in a variable.

```
generate: {
    routes: function () {
        let dedicatedServers = servers.dedicatedServers.map(server => `/products/dedicated-servers/${server.id}`)
        let cloudServers = servers.cloudServers.map(server => `/products/cloud-servers/${server.id}`)
        return Promise.all([dedicatedServers, cloudServers]).then(values => {
            return values.join().split(',');
        })
    }
}
```